# Dynamic Blitz Template not loading currentUser

Tags: templating, plugins, plugin-blitz

I have a Dynamic Blitz template with a currentUser if statement within it. For some reason, it's not working and I can't figure out why.

**It gets loaded in as follows:**

```
{{ craft.blitz.getTemplate('brands/_followButton', { elementId: entry.id }) }}
```

**The code on the page running it:**

```
 {% if currentUser %}
  {% if craft.follow.check({ elementId: entry.id }) %}
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-light py-2 px-3 mr-2" rel="nofollow" href="{{ craft.follow.unfollowUrl(entry.id) }}"><span class="material-icons mr-2 md-18">favorite</span>Unfollow</a>
  {% else %}
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-light py-2 px-3 mr-2" rel="nofollow" href="{{ craft.follow.followUrl(entry.id) }}"><span class="material-icons mr-2 md-18">favorite_border</span>Follow</a>
  {% endif %}

  {% else %}
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-light py-2 px-3 mr-2" rel="nofollow" href="/register"><span class="material-icons mr-2 md-18">favorite_border</span>Follow</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If you hit the ``_followButton`` template template directly does it show correctly?

Comment: @RitterKnight What do you mean sorry?

Comment: The partial loads perfectly when I'm not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using

```
  {% if craft.follow.check({ elementId: elementId }) %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. Test with the following code in `brands/_followButton`.

```
{{ currentUser ? 'Logged in' : 'Logged out' }}
```

> For some reason, it's not working and I can't figure out why.

Can you explain what specifically is not working? And provide the version of Blitz that you're using?

Comment: Removing the follow button code within the partial and replacing it with the above renders "Logged In" and "Logged Out" in both states fine. So it must come down to the "followCheck" and entry.id.